# How to call custom back-end methods (parsing objects) using Typescript and Angular resources

Tags: angularjs, api, service, typescript

I've been struggling for weeks now to get custom service calls to work using Typescript / Angular / C#.  I can't seem to find any viable solution online, and the more I look the more I get confused.

My current solution has been structured based mostly on Pluralsight courses.
I'm understanding the general connectivity from HTML => Angular (controllers/ models / services), but struggling with the Angular services => C# API controller connection.

Current structure:

**app.ts**

```html
module App {
    
    var main = angular.module("Scheduler", ["ngRoute", "App.Services"]);
    main.config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"];
    function routeConfig($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider): void {

        $routeProvider
            .when("/schedule",
            {
                templateUrl: "/app/scheduler/views/scheduler.html",
                controller: "ScheduleCtrl as sch"

            })
            .otherwise("/schedule");
    }
}
```

**services.ts**

```html
module App.Services {
    angular.module("App.Services", ["ngResource"]);
}
```

**controller.ts**

```html
module App.Scheduler {
    
    export interface IScheduleParams extends ng.route.IRouteParamsService {
        scheduleId: number;
    }

    export class ScheduleCtrl implements IScheduleModel {

        scheduleResource: ng.resource.IResourceClass<App.Services.IScheduleResource>;

        static $inject = ["$routeParams", "scheduleService", "$scope"];
        constructor(private $routeParams: IScheduleParams,
                    private scheduleService: App.Services.SchedulerService,
                    public schedule: Schedule) {

            this.scheduleResource = scheduleService.getScheduleResource();

            this.schedule = new Schedule(0, 0, new Array<PaymentEntry>(), 0, new Array <ScheduleEntry>());
        }

        generateSchedule(): void {

            //todo: Need to call the backend service here to generate entries

           var returnedSchedules = this.scheduleService.generateSchedules(this.schedule);
}

}
```

**schedulerService.ts**

```html
module App.Services {


//INTERFACES
    //services
    export interface ISchedulerService {
        getScheduleResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IScheduleResource>;
        generateSchedules(schedule: App.Scheduler.Schedule): App.Scheduler.ScheduleEntry[];  //custom service call
    }

    //resources
    export interface IScheduleResource 
        extends ng.resource.IResource<App.Scheduler.ISchedule> {
    }

    
//CLASSES
    //Schedule Service
    export class SchedulerService implements ISchedulerService {

        static $inject = ["$resource"];

        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        }

        //Read operations (single / list)  -- this works fine
        getScheduleResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IScheduleResource> {
            return this.$resource("api/scheduler/GetSchedules/:scheduleId");
        }

        //custom operations  -- **!! NEED HELP HERE PLEASE !!**
        generateSchedules(schedule: App.Scheduler.Schedule): App.Scheduler.ScheduleEntry[] {

          return this.$resource("api/schedule/GenerateSchedules/:schedule");
          //I need to be able to pass in a Schedule object and receive an array of objects back
        }

    }

    angular
        .module("Scheduler")
        .service("schedulerService", SchedulerService);
}
```

**models.ts**

```html
module App.Scheduler {

//INTERFACES

    export interface ISchedule {
        param1: number;
        payments: Array<IPaymentEntry>;
        schedules?: Array<IScheduleEntry>;

    }

    export interface IPaymentEntry {
        param1: number;
        param2: number;
    }

    export interface IScheduleEntry {
        param1: number;
        param2: string; 
        param3: number;
    }

//CLASSES
    export class Schedule {

        constructor(public param1?: number,
                    public payments?: Array<IPaymentEntry>,
                    public schedules?: Array<IScheduleEntry>) {

        }
    }

    export class PaymentEntry implements IPaymentEntry {

        constructor(public param1?: number,
                    public param2?: number) {
    
        }
    }

    export class ScheduleEntry implements IScheduleEntry {

        constructor(public param1: number,
                    public param2: string,
                    public param3: number) {
        }
    }

}
```

**ApiController.CS**

```
public class SchedulerController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Schedule> GetSchedules()
    {
        //...
    }

    public Schedule GetSchedules(int id)
    {
        //...        
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<PaymentEntry> GenerateSchedules([FromBody]Schedule schedule)
    {
       //todo: add random logic here 
        return new Schedule();
    }
```

Any guidance or a working example of how to successfully call the *generateSchedules* method from the **schedulerService.ts** to the **ApiController.CS** would be greatly appreciated to and from the API controller would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cant really test a C# API, but here is what has been working for me using TypeScript and Rest API.

**Update2** Added a full github example; see at the end of this answer the section called GitHub Example.

**Update:** See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wNrAOG6IcnOReJiiCrAC?p=preview) To display the dummy data, I have this in the HTML:

```
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="s in vm.returnedSchedules">{{s.param1}} - {{s.param2 }}</li>
 </ul>
```

**models.ts**

```
export interface IScheduleEntry extends ng.resource.IResource<IScheduleEntry> {
    param1: number;
    param2: string; 
    param3: number;
}

export interface IScheduleEntryResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IScheduleEntry> {
}
```

**schedulerService.ts**

```
generateSchedules(schedule: App.Scheduler.Schedule): IScheduleEntryResource {
      return <IScheduleEntryResource> this.$resource("api/schedule/GenerateSchedules/:schedule”, { schedule: schedule } );
    }
```

This is important to notice the cast to 'IScheduleEntryResource' and I added passing the parameter using { schedule: schedule }. The first one points to :schedule in the URL and the second one to your method parameter.

**In controller:**

```
class OrganizationsController {
  returnedSchedules: App.Scheduler.IScheduleEntry[];

  static $inject = [‘scheduleService’];
  constructor(scheduleService: App.Services.SchedulerService) {
(…)
  this.returnedSchedules = this.scheduleService.generateSchedules(this.schedule).query();
```

So, I define returnedSchedules as an array App.Scheduler.IScheduleEntry and call .query() to populate it based on the service method we defined. Then, returnedSchedules is properly typed.

To debug API calls I do:

```
this.scheduleService.generateSchedules(this.schedule).query().$promise.then(
       (data) => {
           console.log("Debug API Success: "+JSON.stringify(data));
       },
       (reason) => {
         console.error("Debug API ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(reason));

       }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Full app (in plnkr):

```
module app {
    'use strict';

    export interface IScheduleEntry extends ng.resource.IResource<IScheduleEntry> {
      param1: number;
      param2: string; 
      param3: number;
    }

    export interface IScheduleEntryResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IScheduleEntry> {
    }

    export class DataAccessService {
        static $inject = ['$resource'];

      constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        console.log('Service started');
      }

      generateSchedules(schedule: App.Scheduler.Schedule): IScheduleEntryResource {
        return <IScheduleEntryResource> this.$resource("data.json/:schedule", { schedule: schedule } );
      }
    }

    export class MainCtrl
    {
        static $inject = ['serviceApi'];
        returnedSchedules: App.Scheduler.IScheduleEntry[];

        constructor(myApi) {
          var vm = this;
          vm.name = 'World!';
          // This is what I use for debugging and then replace it with the online below marked as final code. You don't need both
          myApi.generateSchedules().query().$promise.then(
             (data) => {
                 console.log("Debug API Success: "+JSON.stringify(data));
             },
             (reason) => {
               console.error("Debug API ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(reason));

             });

          //Final code
          //vm.returnedSchedules = myApi.generateSchedules().query();
        }
    }

    console.log('app.ts ... started!');
    angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .service('serviceApi', DataAccessService)
    ;


}
```

**Class**

The plunker has been updated to add the Class Example:

As IScheduleEntry extends ng.resource.IResource one will need to implement all the methods of ngResource. In your application you can use IScheduleEntry and it will be strongly type.

```
(...)
mySchedule: IScheduleEntry;
(...)
```

mySchedule.param1 will exist and be a number, mySchedule.param2 a string, and for instance mySchedule.param4 wont exist and will not compile. So, you can use IScheduleEntry as a type in your app and that work.

If you still need to a class with constructor and methods, they are options like composition or factory or a service helper. Here is a rough idea using composition:

```
 export class ScheduleEntry {
      schedule: IScheduleEntry;

      constructor(private ScheduleResource: IScheduleEntryResource) {
        this.schedule = new ScheduleResource();
      }

      init(param1: number, param2: string, param3: number): void {
        this.schedule.param1 = param1;
        this.schedule.param2 = param2;
        this.schedule.param3 = param3;
      }
    }
```

In the service I create the ScheduleEntry via getScheduleEntry:

```
 export class DataAccessService {
        static $inject = ['$resource'];

      constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        console.log('Service started');
      }

      getScheduleEntry(): ScheduleEntry {
        return new ScheduleEntry(<IScheduleEntryResource>this.$resource('/ScheduleEntry', {}));
      }
    }
```

And the usage in the app looks like this:

```
constructor(myApi) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = 'World!';
    vm.returnedSchedules = myApi.generateSchedules().query();

    // Class ScheduleEntry Example
    var myEntry:ScheduleEntry = myApi.getScheduleEntry();
    myEntry.init(1, 'a value', 3);
    vm.name = JSON.stringify(myEntry); // Update web page with value
    myEntry.schedule.$save(); // Call JSON REST api
}
```

The init functions replace your constructor with parameters; it sets the three values in one call. You can add functions and members to the class. If you want the JSON object and the $get, $query, $save, etc. you can do 'myEntry.schedule.$get()', etc. In my example I used '$save' which will return an error as the plunkr does not have a real API, but that shows that ngResource sends a POST as expected. That is one way to keep you ScheduleEntry class.

**Github Example**

Here is a [github example](https://github.com/gregorifaroux/nodejsexample) that I am using to develop a tutorial. I have not finalized the tutorial yet, but the code is working. It is using Express to simulate a small REST API that stores data in the memory. It includes both a Javascript client example and Typescript examples in the public directory. You can follow the instructions to download and run using node. There is also a [live version on OpenShift.](http://nodejs-wetwire.rhcloud.com/indextypescript.html)

Look at the console to see some of the debug information.

The app allows to add, delete, edit, and search users.

In apiservices.ts I create IUser, IUserResouce, and an example of a class User that includes a IUser (composition). It also creates a custom ngResource action called update and I use a service to wrap ngResource:

```
module Api {


    export interface IUser extends ng.resource.IResource<IUser> {
        userid: number;
        firstname: string;
        lastname: string;
    }

    export interface IUserResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IUser> {
        update(IUser): IUser
    }

    export class User {
          user: IUser;
          static $inject = ['apiService'];

          constructor(api: Api.ApiService) {
            this.user = api.newUser();
          }

          init(userid: number, firstname: string, lastname: string): void {
            this.user.userid = userid;
            this.user.firstname = firstname;
            this.user.lastname = lastname;
          }

          getFirstname(): string {
            return this.user.firstname;
          }

          getLastname(): string {
            return this.user.lastname;
          }

          toString(): string {
            return JSON.stringify(this.user);
          }

          save(): ng.IPromise<IUser> {
            return this.user.$save();
          }
        }

    export class ApiService {
        static $inject = ['$resource'];
        UserResource: IUserResource;

        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
            console.log("ApiService constructor ");

            this.UserResource = <IUserResource>this.$resource('/api/individuals/:userid',
                {userid: '@userid'},
                {
                    'update': {
                               method: 'PUT',
                               isArray: false
                           }
                });
        }

        public getUsername(): String {
            return "gregorifaroux@gmail.com";
        }

        public getUserResource(): IUserResource {
            return this.UserResource;
        }

        public getUsers(): IUser[] {
            return this.UserResource.query();
        }

        public newUser(): IUser {
            return new this.UserResource();
        }

        public findById(anId: number): IUser {
            if (anId) {
                return this.UserResource.get({
                    'userid': anId
                });
            }
            return this.newUser();
        }

        public deleteById(anId): IUser {
            if (!anId) {
                return;
            }
            return this.UserResource.delete({
                'userid': anId
            });
        }

        public save(anUser: IUser, aCallback: Function): void {
            console.log('Service.save ' + JSON.stringify(anUser));
            if (anUser.userid) {
                this.UserResource.update(anUser).$promise.then((result) => { aCallback() }, (reason) => {
                    console.error('Api.save ERROR ' + JSON.stringify(reason));
                });
            } else {
                anUser.$save(aCallback);
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('Api', ['ngResource']).service('apiService', ApiService);
}
```

In the main app's constructor I include an example of a User class:

```
// Example using a class with composition (instead of using interface)
var myUser: Api.User = new Api.User(vm.api);
myUser.init(null, 'Neville', 'Stackoverflow');
console.log('Debug Stackoverflow: '+myUser.toString());
console.log('Debug Stackoverflow firstname: '+myUser.getFirstname());
myUser.save();

// Get all the users from the memory store see server.js
vm.individuals = vm.api.getUsers();
```

The main app is in app typescript.ts:

```
module nodejsexample {

    class MainCtrl {
        static $inject = ['apiService'];
        individuals: Api.IUser[];
        individualToSave: Api.IUser;
        query: {
            userid: number,
            result: Api.IUser
        };

        constructor(private api: Api.ApiService) {
            console.log("home.controller constructor " + this.api.getUsername());
            var vm = this;

            // Create a blank user to add new items or edit existing ones
            vm.individualToSave = vm.api.newUser();


            // Object to query the datastore and stores the return value in result
            vm.query = {
                userid: 1,
                result: null
            };

            // Example using a class with composition (instead of using interface)
            var myUser: Api.User = new Api.User(vm.api);
            myUser.init(null, 'Neville', 'Stackoverflow');
            console.log('Debug Stackoverflow: '+myUser.toString());
            console.log('Debug Stackoverflow firstname: '+myUser.getFirstname());
            myUser.save();

            // Get all the users from the memory store see server.js
            vm.individuals = vm.api.getUsers();

        }

        save(): void {
            var vm = this;
            console.log('save: ' + JSON.stringify(vm.individualToSave));
            vm.api.save(vm.individualToSave, function(item, putResponseHeaders) {
                vm.individuals = vm.api.getUsers();
            });
            vm.individualToSave = vm.api.newUser();
        }

        search() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.query.result = vm.api.findById(vm.query.userid);
        }

        edit(anUserId): void {
            var vm = this;
            var result = vm.individuals.filter(function(item) {
                return item.userid == anUserId;
            });
            if (result.length > 0) {
                vm.individualToSave = angular.copy(result[0]);
            }
        }

        cancel(): void {
            var vm = this;
            vm.individualToSave = vm.api.newUser();
        }

        delete(anUserId) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.api.deleteById(anUserId);
            var result = vm.individuals.filter(function(item) {
                return item.userid == anUserId;
            });
            if (result.length > 0) {
                vm.individuals.splice(vm.individuals.indexOf(result[0]), 1);
            }

        }
    }


    console.log('app.ts ... started!');


    angular.module('nodejsexample', ['Api'])
        .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
        ;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gregori, 
I've followed your logic, and kinda-sorta understand what's going on...
however I am getting the following error:

    TS2420: Class 'ScheduleEntry' incorrectly implements interface     'IScheduleEntry'.  
    Property '$get' is missin gin the type 'ScheduleEntry'

on my class:
export class ScheduleEntry implements IScheduleEntry {

        constructor(public param1: number,
                    public param2: string,
                    public param3: number) {
        }
    }

Comment: @Neville here is a plunker with a working version in TypeScript. I simulated the API via a JSON file that contains an array of JSON object: https://plnkr.co/edit/wNrAOG6IcnOReJiiCrAC?p=preview

Comment: @Neville You do not need a ScheduleEntry class...  at least, in my apps, I do not need it (see the plnkr) Let me know.

Comment: I need the class due to the rest of my applications' shared views and objects being utilised from the directives etc. so can't get rid of it.
I'm still experiencing the $get error as mentioned above though.  I've tried various usages, return classes, resources etc.  But it all boils down to the $get error for some reason.   Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You can use IScheduleEntry in your project and it will be typed. For instance schedule: IScheduleEntry will have schedule.param1 defined as a string and schedule.another will not exist. If you still need a constructor or additional method, you could look at composition instead of inheritance. I am updating my answer and let me know. I would need to test it.

Comment: the $get is the first of the error, it will require you to implement all the ngResource method. I updated the end of my answer with an example of composition. Let me know if that helps. What methods would you need on that class that are not in ngResource? Just the constructor you wrote in your question?

Comment: I updated the plunker with an example of the class ScheduleEntry that uses composition (over inheritance) and the answer's last section called 'class'. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Neville any luck?

Comment: unfortunately not mate.
I think I might be going at this the wrong way.
One of my colleagues mentioned that I need to look at $http post instead of a resource service - so I'll be looking into that this week.

Comment: @Neville Sorry to hear. Yes, $http will work, but you will have to write more callbacks. I started to $http, and then move to ngResource. Also, I updated the answer to add a Github example and a live version that I developed to create a tutorial. The tutorial is not written yet, but the code shows how to user ngResource with Typescript, custom method, a class with composition, and uses Express to simulate a small REST API that stores data in memory. Good luck.